# Should we require to install sitemind web agent to both system in java

Tags: spring-security, siteminder

I have one application says "app1"(main application support login) which is deploy some different machine tomcat server and another application says "app2" which also deployed in another machine tomcat server. So, should i need to install siteminder web agent to both the machine or it is on only in "appl2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a traditional reverse proxy (apache with mod_proxy) or SiteMinder Secure Proxy Server to handle the Web Agent work and forward traffic to the destination web/app servers.

Secure Proxy Server enables your Single Sign-On environment to have "agentless" capabilities.  You will still have 1 or more SiteMinder Web Agents (depending on the number of proxies that are deployed), but the web and application servers will not need to have any agents installed.  The web/app servers only need to be able to consume the HTTP Headers provided by SiteMinder.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of agent you are using- if you're using a web agent for a web server (IIS, Apache), you could just install it on that box assuming it handles requests to both app servers.  If you are installing the agent for the app server, Siteminder could log the user into the app on the "app1" server, and then the app/app server token could be passed to "app2"